# current block height

Tags: json-rpc

How do I figure out the current number of blocks?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to modify the bitcoin client at all - you can use [JSON-RPC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29) and call [getblockcount](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list).

Comment: It's altcoin-dev, I need height to recalculate difficulty after fork.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. There's no variable nHeight in ComputeMinWork.

Comment: It's true. It's not possible, because, does not have position on blockchain yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using someone else's server you can just use the response from a HTTP call to http://blockexplorer.com/q/getblockcount